can I have bright colors in vim's highlighting scheme?
When we configure any terminal software (let's say terminator) we define 2 rows of color palette - echo -e "\e[34m blue number 1\n\e[94m blue number 2\e[0m" clearly shows 2 different shades of blue. 
Meanwhile, I am experimenting with /usr/share/vim/vim82/syntax/yaml.vim trying to set vim's colors according to my taste. But I do have difficulties in forcing vim to use colors from bottom row of terminator's colors.
My yaml.vim contains:
hi yamlComment                        ctermbg=lightblue ctermfg=blue
hi yamlBlockMappingKey                ctermbg=lightblue ctermfg=darkblue

And example.yml file:
- hosts: ans1
  tasks:
  - name: "task-name: /home/use/.profile"
    ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
      name: /home/use/.profile
      line: "bash-doc package"
      state: present
#    check_mode: yes
    register: res_home_profile
#    failed_when: res_home_profile.rc == 0
#    ignored_when: res_home_profile.rc == 0

Now when I open it in vim all shades of blue are united - foreground and background cannot be distinguished.
screen that shows lightblue and darkblue are the same 
How do I force vim to use bottom row of palette?
As of now it is 20.04.6 LTS with vim 8.1.1847

What version of Ubuntu are you using?

As of now it is 20.04.6 LTS with vim 8.1.1847
